# Windows phone 8 web browser resolution issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

When I loaded external website using web browser control in c# windows phone 8, Content are loaded without issue, but **Content are too small**. User has to zoom for view content properly. 
Is this a resolution issue? 
How can I fix this?

Here is my code,

```
WebBrowser myBrowser = new WebBrowser();
Uri targetUrl = new Uri(@"http://.../.../");
myBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
myBrowser.Navigate(targetUrl);
ContentPanel.Children.Add(myBrowser);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use meta in your html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
```